# Moving One Vertex Also Moves The Other

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices

How would I move only one vertex in "texturing"?

Result:
[image: Problem example]

And it doesn't matter what Selection mode am using, it happens to all of these:
[image: Selection Mode with Edge Select toggled]

Comment: Maybe you should seperate the uvs. im not sure if this would make a difference, but if you have a sub surface modifier I would reccomend disabling it to add your texture because sometimes one vertex effects another with that modifier. But im no professional so, I hope this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use_uv_select_sync on. You're moving both UVs because they're the same vertex on the mesh. Click the toggle to the left of the selection mode buttons in your picture.